# jquery parses json as array and object at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have simple json string generated with php json_encode() function().

```
   array(3) {
  [38105]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "29428"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "79332"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "41199"
    }
  }
  [38110]=>
  array(3) {
    [3]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "29429"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "79333"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "41201"
    }
  }
  [38115]=>
  array(3) {
    [6]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "29430"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "79334"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(10) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(5) "79334"
    }
  }
}
```

In template php output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ProductMediaGallery = <?php echo json_encode($block->getRelatedProductsGalleryImages()); ?>;
</script>
```

The problem is that this function interprets first set as array, and rest as objects, so I can't get first item of set.

```
function createZoomOverlay() {
    if (typeof ProductMediaGallery !== 'undefined') {

        $.each(ProductMediaGallery, function(key,value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Chrome console output

```
[Object, Object, Object]
Object {3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object}
Object {6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object}
```

Comment: That first block isn't JSON.  It looks like it might be some version of PHP's var_dump/print_r, or maybe, as Rory said, Firebug output.

Comment: An array must, strictly speaking, be indexed starting from 0 and ending in (length-1) with no gaps in between. If it doesn't it's an object.

Comment: Thnaks, @apokryfos , that indeed was the issue.